# What are the javascript performance tradeoffs in adding id's to dom elements?

Tags: jquery, html

For example, I have a website which has a dynamically-generated segment of its dom which looks roughly like this:

```
<div id="master">
  <div class="child"> ... </div>
  <div class="child"> ... </div>
  <div class="child"> ... </div>
  ...
  <div class="child"> ... </div>
</div>
```

There might be hundreds of child elements in this manner, and they, too, might have yet more children.  At present, none of them have id's except for the master.  Javascript manipulates them via dom-walking. It's a little scary.

I'd like to add id's, *e.g.*:

```
<div id="master">
  <div id="child1" class="child"> ... </div>
  <div id="child2" class="child"> ... </div>
  <div id="child3" class="child"> ... </div>
  ...
  <div id="childN" class="child"> ... </div>
</div>
```

What are the tradeoffs in adding id's to these divs?  Certainly, jQuery must maintain a hash of id's, so there's going to be some sort of performance hit. Any general guidelines in when adding additional id's is a *bad* idea?  Is jQuery so awesome that, in practice, it doesn't matter?

Comment: Can we see how you intend to query these elements?

Comment: There's an AJAX request that will fetch a set of ID's from the database which are to receive special markup.  E.g., I might want to highlight children { 5, 13, 25, ...}.  The subsets of children-to-query is not known at page-render time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Certainly, jQuery must maintain a hash of ids

Nope. It's the browser that (optionally, as an optimisation) keeps a lookup of `id` to node.

If you interact with objects in a way that causes jQuery to add `data` to an element (including if you add an event listener), then it will add its own jquery-id to the element for lookup purposes. But it'll do that regardless of whether the element has an `id` attribute.

Add `id`​s if you need to pick out a particular element from the rest. But there's no point in adding `childN` attributes to *every* child when you already have classes. The selector `#master>.child` is likely to be faster than `#master>[id^=child]`, and certainly much faster than fetching each `idN` separately in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

IDs, being unique, are faster than classes when querying a page. They only apply to one element.

That being said, adding IDs to everything does add a lot of clutter to your code. Dom-walking from the parent is usually more convenient programming-wise now that frameworks do the heavy-lifting for us.

But often we want to perform functions on entire groups of elements. In this case, using classes makes sense. Doing a group function on a whole bunch of IDs would be inefficient.

Adding the IDs themselves does not add any performance hit, it all depends on how you intend to use your page.